# Jenkins. Exception during Fingerprinting

Tags: jenkins

Cloned a job from an old master jenkins (v.1.573) to a new master jenkins(v.1.599) and it is building successfully although there is an exception that happens after each build.

The slave that this was running on in the old master node has been reconfigured to be a slave on the new master node.

I have searched online and there is not much info on how to troubleshoot this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 56:45.463s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu May 14 11:37:20 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 221M/10715M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Asynchronous execution failure
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$3.adapt(Channel.java:755)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$3.adapt(Channel.java:750)
    at hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:55)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenBuilder.waitForAsynchronousExecutions(AbstractMavenBuilder.java:186)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:143)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR: Asynchronous execution failure
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$3.adapt(Channel.java:755)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$3.adapt(Channel.java:750)
    at hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:55)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenBuilder.waitForAsynchronousExecutions(AbstractMavenBuilder.java:186)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:143)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR: Asynchronous execution failure
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to hudson.model.Fingerprint
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$3.adapt(Channel.java:755)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$3.adapt(Channel.java:750)
    at hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:55)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenBuilder.waitForAsynchronousExecutions(AbstractMavenBuilder.java:186)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:143)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to hudson.model.Fingerprint
    at hudson.model.Fingerprint.load(Fingerprint.java:1250)
    at hudson.model.Fingerprint.load(Fingerprint.java:1238)
    at hudson.model.FingerprintMap.load(FingerprintMap.java:94)
    at hudson.model.FingerprintMap.load(FingerprintMap.java:45)
    at hudson.util.KeyedDataStorage.get(KeyedDataStorage.java:154)
    at hudson.model.FingerprintMap.get(FingerprintMap.java:79)
    at hudson.model.FingerprintMap.get(FingerprintMap.java:45)
    at hudson.util.KeyedDataStorage.getOrCreate(KeyedDataStorage.java:108)
    at hudson.model.FingerprintMap.getOrCreate(FingerprintMap.java:65)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter$1.call(MavenFingerprinter.java:125)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter$1.call(MavenFingerprinter.java:112)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild$ProxyImpl.execute(MavenBuild.java:419)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild$ProxyImpl2.execute(MavenBuild.java:547)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor836.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.model.Executor$1.call(Executor.java:579)
    at hudson.util.InterceptingProxy$1.invoke(InterceptingProxy.java:23)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.execute(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuildProxy$Filter$AsyncInvoker.call(MavenBuildProxy.java:294)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.CallableDecorator.call(CallableDecorator.java:18)
    at hudson.remoting.CallableDecoratorList$1.call(CallableDecoratorList.java:21)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd to update to an old (and non-LTS) Jenkins version like 1.599, so I would normally say that you should try with the latest version (currently Jenkins 1.613).

But in any case, it looks like there is already a very similar issue recorded, with a few people tracking it:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23566

It would likely be helpful if you could contribute your experience and OS/Jenkins version info there.